# Is there any way I can implement showSoftInputOnFocus in Android for API 14?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm designing an app where in the `AndroidManifest.xml` I have set

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

to prevent the keyboard from popping up annoyingly. But I want the keyboard to pop up on an `EditText` after a certain animation is done. However, the `minSdk` in my app is set to be 14 & the method to pop up the keyboard,

`editText.showSoftInputOnFocus(true)`

is supported only on APIs 21 & above.

So I was wondering if there was any workaround for it for API 14.

Thank You for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the soft keyboard to appear, use `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` method of `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

simply call

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

if not working also add below line

```
editText.performClick();
```

It will work for all versions.

you can also use this method

```
public static void showSoftKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);        
    imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: This isn't popping up the keyboard

Comment: Yes! It still isn't popping up the keyboard. Could it be because I have set the permission in Mainest as hidden?

Comment: Wouldn't the static method here be executed before the rest of the code?And how do I associate this piece of code to my editText?

Comment: yes it can be, if you want your keyboard to be hidden initially you can code single line to do it in onCreate, by this way you do not need to set activity property. Try this and let me know what are you facing after it

Comment: you can remove static.

Comment: call method like this "method(activity context,getWindow().getDecoreView())" on editText touch or click